# Numbers with divisors adding up to it

Tags: number-theory

I have been working with semiperfect numbers (note: semiperfect numbers are numbers that have some, but not all, of its divisors add up to itself) with divisors mentioned above in arithmetic progression. How can I prove  that all such semiperfect numbers are numbers in the form $6n$? (we assume that there is more than one divisor being summed up)

My idea is to show that it can be done with 3 divisors (with only the $6n$ case), and only three divisors. (I have already disproved the two divisors case)

The $6n$ numbers are a case of three divisors, the divisors being $n, 2n, 3n$.

After thinking about this for a while, I really want to see a proof; I just can't think of a solution.

Comment: Hint, using six divisors as an example: the three larger divisors of $N$ must all exceed $N/6$, and thus must be a subset of $\{N/5, N/4, N/3, N/2\}$. Can three of those be in arithmetic progression?

Comment: I'm sort of seeing it, but still not seeing a solid proof.

Comment: That's okay; take more than 14 minutes to think about it (interesting math is never done in an instant).

Comment: I can show how none of the subsets of three elements of that set can be in arithmetic progression, but what about the other three, smaller divisors?

Comment: Also, I think I can confidently claim that the only such numbers are in the form 6n (I've looked at all the semiperfect numbers up to 1000; only multiples of 6 work).